# C# Doing a 2 dimension matrix with randoms numbers between 10 and 25

Tags: c#, matrix, random

It may seems ridiculous or like I didn't even try, but trust me I did.

all I can do is this:

```
        float[,] notes = new float[6, 3];
        int l, c;
```

after that am lost trying things like this

```
        for (l = 0; l <= notes.GetUpperBound(0); l++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c <= notes.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,5}   ", notes[l, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

But not much is working here.
Not to mention am not even sure how to incorporate the randomizer in this... also it needs to count odd numbers in each columns.

So I need guidance of what to do and who to do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

To get a random number you can use the [`Random` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int number = rand.Next(0, 26); // Will get you a number between 0 and 25
```

You can use a simple nested loop with two `for` to populate the matrix with the random number generated, and then you can print it if you want.

Comment: `rand.Next(0, 25)` actually gives you numbers ranging from 0-24 - the upper bound in `Next` is exclusive.